# Compare Two JSON object

Tags: android, json, gson

I am having JSON object like

```
{
key1:value1,
key2:value2
key3:value3
}
```

and i will write this JSON content to file.(Done)

For next interval of time i am getting JSON Object as

```
{
    key1:newValue1,
    key2:value2
    key3:newValue3
    }
```

I need to find out difference between each values. and need to write new json into file

```
{
key1:(value1- newValue1),
key2:(value2 - value2)
key3:(value3- newValue3)
}
```

How can i achieve it.? Please help.

Comment: The values will be int type and you want to update the value to the subtraction value, is that correct?

Comment: @Neo ya correct. Any math operation.

Comment: Ok I will write you some code as an answer

Comment: Thanks @Neo It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below just iterates through the keys of your testObject, subtracts the value of the object from file and puts the result of this subtraction back to the testObject... Than you can save, or do whatever you want to do with the values in testObject

```
        for(Iterator<String> iterator = testObject.keys(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String key = iterator.next();

            try {
                int testValue = testObject.getInt(key);
                int fileValue = fileObject.getInt(key);
                int differenceValue = testValue - fileValue;
                testObject.put(key, differenceValue);
            } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

Comment: Is that what you expected?